# IIS Express / VS Config works only for myself, not other users

Tags: visual-studio-2010, authentication, windows-authentication, iis-express

Using Visual Studio 2010 and IIS Express.  The web site site I'm debugging will only accept logins from my domain account.  If I connect to the site from a different system logged in as someone else, I'm given a 401 error after the credentials are rejected several times.  I don't *think* this is a firewall issue, as I've disabled all of those I can find.  Once IIS Express is running, I can see the ports its bound to are accepting requests:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:64611          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:64611             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

From IISExpress/Config/ApplicationHost.config:

```
<location path="CAF">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
       </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The application's web.config (relevant section):

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

And in Visual Studio, the project shows "Anonymous Authentication = Disabled" and "Windows Authentication = Enabled".

I start Visual Studio as "Administrator" (shift, click, "Run as Administrator") otherwise the error "Unable to connect to the configured development web server, Failed to register URL http://*:64611/ for site CAF application /.  Error description: Access is denied (0x800700005)" occurs.  Starting VS as Admin fixes that problem, and the site works normally except it ONLY authenticates me.

I'm kind of stumped here, and I can't really test out some multi-user features unless I can connect as a couple of different users.

Comment: "I can't really test out some multi-user features unless I can connect as a couple of different users." The question gets no answer, and maybe the cause is that you didn't make it very clear what that meant.